# Recompile NHibernate 2 sources

Tags: nhibernate

We're using NH 2 and need some features from NH 3 (`JOIN ...`**`AND (...)`**). It's quite easy to copy them from sources. So I wonder if there can be any unexpected errors in application after recompiling NH 2 and using instead of the one compiled by developers of NH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems may occur if you have other pre-built assemblies which reference a specific NH version. In that case you may need to do an [assembly binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Personally, I would try to upgrade everything to NH 3 if I wanted a feature from it because that way I don't have to concern with managing a forked version of an assembly.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't move to 3.0 because our target .NET is 3.0 and NH 3 needs 3.5